# Redux state is filled but wont render in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im trying to render data from redux state to react component, from redux dev tool its filled also no error.

I dont know where's the wrong thing because it seems fine, i can get the array state data rendered using map, but for the single object its not working. the state is **pasien**

**My Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  listPasien: [],
  pasien: null,
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};
```

**My React Component**

```
const ProfilePasien = ({ getPasien, pasien: { pasien, loading }, match }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getPasien(match.params.id);
  }, [getPasien, match.params.id]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <p>{pasien.id_pasien}</p>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ProfilePasien.propTypes = {
  getPasien: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  pasien: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  pasien: state.pasien
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPasien })(ProfilePasien);
```

it keep returning empty on page.

Comment: is there an error in the browser console? there are many things that could go wrong that would lead to an empty page

Comment: None, mostly unrelated errors. I think i found the culprit, my api is returning array object for getting single result by id after checking postman again. never got problem like this before because using mysql instead mongodb now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's solved, turns out my API sending array of object instead single object to my redux state.